# Doxygen Doesn't expand macros

Tags: c++, macros, doxygen

This seems to be a really trivial task and yet I am not able to get Doxygen to expand the macro. I've used version 1.6.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.6 and 1.8.6. I've also done plenty of searches on Google, but still failed miserably.

I've got a c++ file which contains only the following lines (copied off Doxygen documentation):

```
#define CONST_STRING const char *
 static CONST_STRING version = "2.xx";
```

I've followed the documentation and set:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
```

Then added the following:

```
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = CONST_STRING
```

then

```
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES (previously NO)
```

All I got from the code generation was:

```
1 #define CONST_STRING const char *
2 static CONST_STRING version = "2.xx";
```

What have I done wrong? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - This user is taking an example straight from the doxygen pages to make a MWE.

Comment: Should have made it clear. This is not a question about C++ syntax/sematic. It's about Doxygen preprocessing source code and expanding macros such as those given above. For this reason #define is a perfectly valid example.

Comment: What makes you think you something has gone wrong, user3257895?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think you have done something wrong?

You should be seeing `version` in the "Variables" section of the documentation page for that source file. If you've enabled source code output, the variable `version` should hyperlink to that variable documentation.

Your documentation will look much better if you preface the definition of the variable with a doxygen comment. Continuing with this example,

```
//! Define a constant string type.
//! @deprecated Use the typedef const_string_t instead.
#define CONST_STRING const char *

//! Software version number
static CONST_STRING version = "2.xx";
```

Comment: Apology if I responded to your question using the wrong method. This is my first time using Stackoverflow. From the example I am expecting the doxygen generated code to be: `static const char * version = "2.xx";` i.e. CONST_STRING is replaced with "const char *". I presume that's what MACRO_EXPANSION means...

Comment: That is not what MACRO_EXPANSION means. The code shown is your code, possibly with doxygen comments deleted. What enabling MACRO_EXPANSION does is tell doxygen's interpreter to preprocess your code prior to parsing. Think of doxygen as a compiler, but with the output being API documentation rather than machine code. The front end of doxygen is very, very similar to the front end of a compiler.

Comment: Thanks David, after your explanation, I went back and re-read the documentation. You were correct and I've misunderstood the description. My misunderstanding was heavily contributed by the fact that Doxygen did not generate the documentation for the variable despite all the correct setting described above including the source code output enabled. This was because the EXTRACT_ALL also needs to be set to YES. Many thanks for the answer!